# How to move a rabbit in a labyrinth to find the carrot without knowing the position of the rabbit and the carrot

Tags: path-finding

I got this question during an interview with a big company:

let`s suppose we have this interface:

```
interface ILabyrinth
{

   // create a labyrinth of size 100*100 max.  Rabbit and carrot are positioned at random locations within the maze.
   void Init();

   // try to move the rabbit in one direction.  return true if the move was successful, returns false otherwise (there was a wall) 
   bool tryMove(Direction d);

   // return true if carrot and rabbit are at the same place.
   bool isSuccess();
```

}

How would you move the rabbit in order to find the carrot ?
We just need to stop once we reached it.

My solution is to apply a classic DFS search except that we need to backtrack the mouse using the tryMove() function since we cannot do it ourself (because the data are contained and modified by the interface  ILabzrinth only.

And I do that by keeping track of the movement of the rabbit in a new map of size 198*198 ( =  (100-1)*2). In this map I save the direction we used to come in that position. so I can backtrack easily.

Do you have any idea how to improve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not too much you can improve, in terms of heuristics, because you are given no clue where the carrot is until you are on top of the carrot. Therefore, in the absence of any heuristics, it is necessary to do a DFS.

In the map of the direction you came from, you can also use the storage as a flag of where you have been to avoid re-exploring places you have already been. You have not indicated if you check this, but if you haven't, then this is one possible area of improvement.

To minimise memory usage, the backtracking of the direction can be stored in a stack. This avoids storing extra data in a large map. Since you probably want to retain the map of flags, you will still want a boolean map. However, this only costs 1 bit per cell (instead of 1 byte for direction).

Comment: They didn't state that the rabbit moves by the same amount each time `tryMove()` is called, but I think that assumption is necessary - otherwise, we can't know if we're moving in a circle *(visiting the same nodes over and over)* or moving inwards in a spiral.

Comment: Let's say the rabbit move from one position to the adjacent one only.

Answer (score 0):

If this was an interview, I hope you mentionned that "mouse and cheese" becomes "rabbit and carrot", which can look like a detail but may be made purposely... (and isSuccess() will never return true if we only move the mouse and never the rabbit!)

Apart from that, I wouldn't habe used a DFS but have moved 1 case for each available branch before going deeper (BFS) because you don't know where the POIs are. Forbid visiting a node except if the new distance is lower than the previous one (but it sould not happend frequently!). Not going backwards (going left when I just moved right) is a plus but encompassed by the previous rule.

Hope it will work for you anyways...
GL!

Edit: I found this : http://www.astrolog.org/labyrnth/algrithm.htm#solve. What I awkwardly proposed here corresponds to the non human-dorable sjortest path, where you recreate a maze locally using a n*n grid with distances (the second shortest-path described I guess...)

BTW what was the question here: to find the carrot? Find a shortest path to it? Retrace the path or not???

Re-edit: After disambiguation, parts of this answer does not suit the problem: The objective is not to fina a shortest path but the carrot, and the rabbit can only be in one square at the time.

Comment: @ronalchn: I don't agree with " in the absence of any heuristics, it is necessary to do a DFS" and I siggest that the lack of information (and Dijkstra) lead to the use of a BFS. The difference with a Dijkstra here is just that we will never reduce the value of a node we already visited.

Comment: I did not used a BFS because I think that would be slower because of the "manual" backtracking which would occurs more often, and thus take more time.
Am I wrong ?

(and I simply made a mistake myself with cheese, carrot, mouse, cheese ... fixed it)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "manual" backtracking. When you find the carrot using your recursive function, the sequence of "return" statements creates a (reversed) route. The number of nodes observed depends on the relative distance between the rabbit and carrot, compared to the size of the map. Also, as soon as there are no weigths for each node, the first solution you find (using BSF) is the best one (or one with the lower cost).

Comment: What I mean by "manual" bactracking:
In a classic BFS (DFS), we put on a queue (stack) the node to visit, and then we pop it and analyze it.
But here, we need to "manually" backtrack the rabbit using tryMove(direction) several times until we reach the node to visit (the popped one).

And I think that applying A BFS will use the tryMove(direction) more often than a DFS (in average).

Because we will backtrack every time we want to change the branch of the "exploring tree" which occurs more often in a BFS than in a DFS (but the backtrack should be shorter in average using the DFS than the BFS)

Comment: Ahah I had exactly the opposite intuition: if the carrot is just next to the rabbit, the DFS can find it instantly, BUT it can make you ride the whole maze, and some cases more than once (unlucky strike). BFS would find it in maximum 4 explored nodes. Also, each square of the maze will be observed at most once using BSF. On the contraty, when the carrot is far, DFS may observe less nodes to find the carrot once, but it will explore other nodes to try and reduce the cost...

Comment: all algorithms have pathological cases, however, looking at worst case algorithmic complexity by number of tryMove() calls, for an n by n map, the worst case for DFS is O(n^2), but the worst case for BFS is O(n^4).

Comment: I had this intuition (DFS worst case being worse than BFS worst case), but could you explain how you calculate these complexities ?

Comment: An n by n map (with a snake shaped maze) is equivalent to a 1 by N map where N=n^2. If you start in the centre of a 1 by N map, DFS explores one side fully before the other side. BFS will move left to explore 1 cell, then right to an unexplored cell, then left again, ... . This costs 1+2+3+...+(N-1) moves. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation for more information.

Comment: @ronalchn "the worst case for DFS is O(n^2), but the worst case for BFS is O(n^4)" The worst cases must have the same tryMove() "complexity": O(n²), corresponding to the fact that you find the carrot in the last square you observe. How did you come to this n^4 estimation? Anyways, I'll edit the post with a "reference" where BFS is mentionned... Actually I think that the evaluation process does not focus on the approach but more on the programming approach. Once again good luck with your application, @taktak004!

Comment: @aname (answering your edit): The question was: How would you move the rabbit in order to find the carrot ? We just need to stop once we reached it.
And I am going to have another interview about that again, and i guess they will ask me how to change the code I wrote in order to retrace the path, to have the shortest path ... and other things like that.

Comment: @aname (answering your last comment): "The worst cases must have the same tryMove() "complexity": O(n²), corresponding to the fact that you find the carrot in the last square you observe."
Here, we are not speaking about the number of cells explored, but the number of cells we have to retrace back. I could not explain it better than ronalchn did in his last comment (even if I am not sure the snake maze is really the worst case, but it shows well the point)

Comment: OK I just understood : the rabbit hasn't got ubiquity! I'm sorry @ronalchn, I just avoided this constraint and thus I must conceed that DFS is not a good option for this problem. You should take a good look at http://www.astrolog.org/labyrnth/algrithm.htm#solve anyways, there are lots of alternatives depending on the interface and objectives you are proposed... Cheers!

Comment: @Aname "the rabbit hasn't got ubiquity! I just avoided this constraint and thus I must conceed that DFS is not a good option for this problem", you meant BFS ?

Or I don't understand your sentence the good way.

To sum up, do you agree or not that since the rabbit hasn't got ubiquity, the DFS is a rather good way to solve the problem (better than a BFS and it is maybe the best way) ?

Comment: Yep you (and ranlchn) were right all the way and I finally understand the trackback since the rabbit must walk back!